# PHP - Application Authorization

Tags: php

I have on PHP application(like industry machine temperature monitoring and reporting).

Now, My client is asking full source code(including server side,client side,Database) of application. My terms to the client is, the product can be modified/used for their own needs but should not be distributed to others without my permission.

My Question:

1. Is any way to monitoring, the application is only used by my client?
2. Can I implement any Authorization/Authentication technique to attain my requirements.

I need your direction/idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may depend on why they need it. You could however encode the "core" of your application using

http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard

http://www.ioncube.com/

http://www.sourceguardian.com/

However this will force you to write a modular part which can still be edited to proved enhancements. This will probably cost you a lot of work.

Comment: FullAck: "It will probably cost you a lot of work"! And don't forget that debugging a encoded application can be much harder if you don't have very sophisticated error logging mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I will do the analysis over your inputs and incorporate appropriate solution. Thanks again.